# How to make inverted smoke in blender 2.8

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to make a kind of inverted smoke. I'm making an animation of the LEM landing on the moon but the flame of the engine is ascending, it need to go down, I tried to rotate the flow but it's not working
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work but you could try to change gravity to -9.81 instead of 9.81? ;)

Comment: I found the solution 2 mins later, i just rotated the smoke domain and i changed the scale

Comment: Where is the gravity setting? my solution is not working for render

Comment: In the scene tab. If it doesn't work try adding a minus in front of some of the smoke properties... density or temperature maybe?

Comment: Gravity setting is in the domain setting but try a vortex as well